# Jquery recall function (inside updatepanel) is not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a jquery function to toggle "ReplyComment" div.

```
function addcommentdiv() {
    $('.in').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $reply = $this.next('.ReplyComment');
        var cevapladisplay = $reply.css('display');
        $reply.toggle();

    });
}
addcommentdiv();

$(document).ready(function () {
    addcommentdiv();
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    addcommentdiv();
});
```

...

```
<ul class="chats">
 <li class="in" >
        blablabla
 </li>
 <div class="ReplyComment" id="ReplyComment">
     blablabla
 </div>
 </ul>
```

This function sometimes work sometimes doesn't.Shortly not working smoothly.
  I can't understand.(inside updatepanel and datalist)

Comment: Where is the `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: @undefined How can I fix it :/

Comment: @JasonP updatepanel>datalist>ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you are adding the click handlers multiple times. To avoid the issue completely, I would recommend using event delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.in', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $reply = $this.next('.ReplyComment');
        var cevapladisplay = $reply.css('display');
        $reply.toggle();

    });
});
```

This will prevent you from needing to rebind the events after every `UpdatePanel` refresh.